# Calculate FocalLength and ExposureTime to more human readable value

Tags: php, exif

I want to convert focal length and exposure time to a more readable value. I have Googled for one hour now and I can't find any functions on GitHub or on any other websites, that converts these to a more human readable values. Here's how it looks like now:

```
'ExposureTime' => string '10/130' (length=6)
'FocalLength' => string '51/10' (length=5)
```

Here's how it should looks like (as shown on [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/105044171@N02/10211361994/meta/)):

```
ExposureTime: 0.077 sec (1/13)
FocalLength: 5.1 mm
```

I know that the answer are right there but how can I calculate it to the right value?

Comment: explode on the `/` to give two values; then divide the first of those by the second, round as appropriate and format for display.... simple Mathematics 101